# Create persistent usb with Déjà Dup

Tags: usb, backup, deja-dup, xrdp, headless

I broke my ubuntu install on a usb, but luckily, I backed up my ubuntu install to google drive.  Since my server is a headless server, I would like to figure out how to restore my ubuntu install without reinstalling Ubuntu, since I can't set up xrdp without a monitor. Since my server is a headless server, I would like to figure out how to restore my ubuntu install without reinstalling Ubuntu, since I can't set up xrdp without a monitor. I do have a Windows 10 laptop with the Ubuntu 18.04 terminal WSL. How would I go about this task?

Broken install is 18.04 Desktop, I was trying to upgrade to 20.04, but the computer shut down half way through, and I have a broken install now.

Comment: What does the headless server have to do with the issue?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I can't do a reinstall easily. A reinstall could make doing the restore easier, but I can't do that.